# Is there a `replicateM` function for the internal monad in a monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Suppose I have something like this:

```
data Environment = ...
data MyState = ...
data Report  = ...

updateState :: Environment -> MyState -> MyState
updateState = ...

report :: MyState -> Report
report = ...

foo :: ReaderT Environment (State MyState) Report 
foo = do env   <- ask
         state <- lift get
         let newState = updateState env state
         lift $ put newState
         return $ report newState
```

What's in my head are simulations of a time process in which I have parameters that will be stored in `Environment`, the dynamical state will be stored in `MyState` and info I wish to collect in each time step of the simulation will be stored in `Report`.

Now, I wan't to run many steps of this simulation and get a list with the reports for each time step.

I usually did this without a `ReaderT` and used to pass the parameters like this:

```
 foo :: Enviroment -> State MyState Report
```

Then I would just do:

```
 manySteps :: Int -> Enviroment -> State MyState [Report]
 manySteps n env = replicate n $ (foo env)
```

I'm getting confused with the types of `lift` and `replicateM`. Is there a combination that would replicate the `State MyState` monad inside the transformer?

In the future I'll replace `ReaderT Environment (State MyState) Report` for `ReaderT Environment (StateT MyState (Rand StdGen)) Report` so it's better to get things right before having this monster type :(.

**edit:** as a side question - is there a better strategy than using `ReaderT Environment (State MyState) Report` ?

Comment: The strategy of using ReaderT and StateT looks reasonable.  For real use I would suggest not using "ask,get,put" directly, define a short alias or helper with a descriptive name and use that instead.  This allows you to edit the implementation of the Monad stack and only have to update the helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concrete example of replicateM here:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State

data Environment = E Int deriving Show
data MyState = S Int deriving Show
data Report  = R String deriving Show

updateState :: Environment -> MyState -> MyState
updateState (E step) (S val) = S $! val + step

report :: MyState -> Report
report (S val) = R (show val)

foo :: ReaderT Environment (State MyState) Report 
foo = do env   <- ask
         state <- get -- lift was not needed
         let newState = updateState env state
         put newState -- lift was not needed
         return $ report newState

run e s m = runState (runReaderT m e) s
```

Note that I removed the "lift" since the ReaderT has a MonadState pass-through instance.  Running foo once gives:

```
*Main> run (E 10) (S 5) foo
(R "15",S 15)
```

I can run foo seven times in a row:

```
*Main> run (E 10) (S 5) (replicateM 7 foo)
([R "15",R "25",R "35",R "45",R "55",R "65",R "75"],S 75)
```

What in the above needs more clarification?

Comment: hum... now I see the source of confusion. I was thinking that if I did `replicateM n foo` I'd get a `ReaderT Environment [(State MyState) Report]`. Now I see that this is OBVIOUSLY not the case. The type doesn't even makes sense...

Comment: How did you get rid of ambiguity for module `Control.Monad.State` in GHCi? (I have packages mtl and monads-tf)

Comment: @ony you can use 'ghci  -XPackageImports ...' and 'import "mtl" Control.Monad.State' or 'ghci  -package mtl ...'

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's enough to prove type if you unsure in the way to use something

```
-- import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

data Environment
data MyState
data Report
data State a b
instance Monad (State a)

foo = undefined :: ReaderT Environment (State MyState) Report
```

Than in GHCi

```
*Main> :t flip replicateM foo
flip replicateM foo
  :: Int -> ReaderT Environment (State MyState) [Report]
```